# Implement multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface using structure map and call specific class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap4

I am using structure map IOC container I am not using the scan with default name convention here.

public interface ICompanyRepository

```
{

    IEnumerable<Company> GetAll();

    Company Get(int id);

    Company Add(Company item);


    bool Update(Company item);

    bool Delete(int id);


}

public class Company1: ICompanyRepository
{
   // Proivide implementation for all interface  methods
}

public class Company2: ICompanyRepository
{
   // Provide implementation for all interface  methods

//Class Company2 will also have new method called DisplayLog
    public void DisplayLog()
    {
        //To do
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement DI using structuremap in my Customer controller class
how can I tell the that i need methods ofcompany1 to be called or methods Company2 to be called?

```
_.Scan(x =>
     {
        x.TheCallingAssembly();

        x.AddAllTypesOf<ICompanyRepository>();

        // or

    });
```

my code:
    private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

```
    public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository)
    {
        customerRepository = CustomerRepository;
    }


    // GET: Customer  
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var customers = customerRepository.GetAll
       //Here i need to be specfic telling i need to call company1 or company2 class methods ?
        return View(customers);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [structuremap - two implementations of same interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602403/structuremap-two-implementations-of-same-interface)

Comment: This is not an Duplicate Question

Answer (score -1):

If you have two concrete implementations of the same interface, you can use StructureMap's named instances so it knows which one to build.

```
// Repo1
public class CompanyRepository1: ICompanyRepository
{
}

// Repo2
public class CompanyRepository2: ICompanyRepository
{
}

// Controller
public CompanyController(ICompanyRepository companyRespository2)
{
    _companyRepository2 = companyRespository2;
}

// StrucureMap registration
For<ICompanyRepository>().Use<CompanyRepository1>().Named("companyRepository1");
For<ICompanyRepository>().Use<CompanyRepository2>().Named("companyRepository2");
```

Comment: I have made the above changes in my MVC controller how do I explicitly specify which class of interface to be used?

Comment: I did changes as you suggested but still, I am not  able to  see  DisplayLog()

Comment: When i did this change it always loads me data from  companyRepository2

Comment: Yes. By naming the parameter in the controller companyRepository2 and setting up StructureMap to provide that instance when that parameter name is used, you are binding the controller to using CompanyRepository2.

Comment: even if i try to load companyRepository1 in the controller it always by default load me companyRepository2